# A CPU with OEM part number bought as a boxed part

Tags: cpu, hardware-rec

According to [CPU World](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-FX-Series%20FX-6350.html) regarding the FX-6350 CPU:

> FD6350FRW6KHK is an OEM/tray microprocessor
>   FD6350FRHKBOX is a boxed microprocessor with fan and heatsink

However, my CPU has `FD6350FRW6KHK` written on top of it, and yet I bought it in a (sealed) box, and it came with heatsink, cooler and even a sticker. This was in 2014. It only caught my attention today when I was switching thermal compound.

Is this to be expected, or a reason to worry?

Comment: Ask the shop you bought it from

Comment: It is completely normal. You are over thinking it... the AMD P/N FD6350FRW6KHK is for the FX-6350 CPU, the P/N FD6350FRHKBOX is a retail box multi-part set that includes a FD6350FRW6KHK CPU and fan/cooler assembly. You order FD6350FRW6KHK for the CPU by itself, or FD6350FRHKBOX for the retail box assembly. Whether you get the CPU by itself (OEM) or in a retail box, the CPU is still exactly the same. I would put this as answer, but I cannot find a reference for it although experience has taught me this is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is completely normal. You are over thinking it...

The AMD P/N FD6350FRW6KHK is for the FX-6350 CPU, the P/N FD6350FRHKBOX is a retail box multi-part set that includes a FD6350FRW6KHK CPU and fan/cooler assembly. You order FD6350FRW6KHK for the CPU by itself, or FD6350FRHKBOX for the retail box assembly.

Whether you get the CPU by itself (OEM) or in a retail box, the CPU is still exactly the same. I would put this as answer, but I cannot find a reference for it although experience has taught me this is true